# How many puzzles do I need to solve in order to finish the game?

Tags: professor-layton-the-last-specter

The Professor Layton games contain certain points in the story where you will need to have solved so many puzzles in order to proceed further.

How many such milestones exist in The Last Spectre, and how many puzzles are required to be solved at each? I would prefer answers without spoilers (simply stating "milestone 1, 2... et cetera would be fine).

Comment: ugh, I wish I could help with this one.  Most Layton games though, I solve ALL the puzzles!

Comment: @agent86 I do as well, but I really enjoy the story in the games, so I prefer to get through it as quickly as possible. This way I also have a whole bunch of puzzles to solve after I've beat the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I just finished the game, so I'm now capable of answering this myself. There are three milestones. The amount of solved puzzles required to proceed past each of them is:

Milestone 1: 25 puzzles
Milestone 2: 50 puzzles
Milestone 3: 80 puzzles